# error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting this error whenever I run the bottom file. The strange thing is that it runs fine when I run it through a terminal. However, when I run it through a web based IDE I get the error.

```py
import cv2
import sys

num_down = 2       # number of downsampling steps
num_bilateral = 7  # number of bilateral filtering steps

img_rgb = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])

# downsample image using Gaussian pyramid
# We use _ in range because we don't care about the actual index
img_color = img_rgb
for _ in range(num_down):
    img_color = cv2.pyrDown(img_color)

# repeatedly apply small bilateral filter instead of applying one large filter
for _ in range(num_bilateral):
    img_color = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_color, d=9, sigmaColor=9, sigmaSpace=7)

# upsample image to original size
for _ in range(num_down):
    img_color = cv2.pyrUp(img_color)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.medianBlur(img_gray, 7)

# detect and enhance edges
img_edge = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_blur, 255,
                                 cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
                                 blockSize=9,
                                 C=2)


# convert back to color, bit-AND with color image
img_edge2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_edge, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
img_cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(img_color, img_edge2)

# save
cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[2], img_cartoon)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "blur.py", line 36, in
>   
>       img_cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(img_color, img_edge2) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:229: error:
>   (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither
>   'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor
>   'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'binary_op'

Comment: That error message generally also include a traceback, which tells you on what statement it occurred. Could you [edit] your question and provide that rather relevant piece of information?

Comment: Edited the post to show where the error occurred.

img_cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(img_color, img_edge2)

Comment: Inspect (e.g. print out) the `shape` and `dtype` of both `img_color` and `img_edge2` just before that statement. | In both cases, you run it with an identical input image, and using the same version of OpenCV?

Comment: For both I get (232, 412, 3) when I inspect their shape. When I inspect the dtype I get TypeError: data type not understood

The OpenCV version is the same. However, the input image was different. I just tried using the same input image I used when I ran it through the terminal and it works just fine when I run it through the web based IDE. 

I then ran the program through the terminal using the input image I used when I got the error, and I'm getting the same error. So, for some reason it doesn't like that particular image.